# Getting styleid and set condition to css

Tags: css, vbulletin

I have a little problem with styling my vbulletin forum.

I have 2 different styles. Both works perfectly. 
I have added new twitter widget to my web and now I am facing a problem with styling it.

I found a way to change css style of this widget, but I have only **one**  external css file. It means, that **BOTH styles uses same css for this widget**. This doesn't look good.

Is there any way to check (within this external css file) which style is user currently using and conditionaly change something in css?

Something like getting the style id and checking in css (I believe I can use php) if it is first style or second.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: generally, there are no conditionals in standard css. You could try using a Body Class depending on which theme is currently active. Then use basic css inheritance to style your widget accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I do realize that. I hoped, that I can use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129699/can-you-use-if-else-conditions-in-css. If it really works it would be more than enough for me.