# can we give if else condition in css without using any framework

Tags: css

i have an image in the background. i need to decide the color of some divs based on that. How can i achieve it directly in CSS instead of any script Or CSS framework

```
if (isBackImgTower){
    color:#fff; //(then i want to apply the color #fff)
}
else{
    color:#000;
}
```

Comment: No, CSS has no logic. Use classes for that

Comment: Your question is looking similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129699/can-you-use-if-else-conditions-in-css

Comment: you are using any server side script? like php,jsp,asp...etc

Comment: This is a duplicate question if I have ever seen one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply NO. CSS does not support logics.

So you will need a css preprocessor like [SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_8) for simple logics like this.

**Sample SCSS** *[This might not give the exact answer - But just to get an idea]*,

```
$isBackImgTower: true;

div {
  @if $isBackImgTower == true {
    color: #fff; 
  } @else {
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

But why not simply use a class with `background-image` property? Is there any reason?

Example,

```
div {
    color: #000;
}
div.isBackImgTower {
    background-image:url('images/tower.jpg');
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: marking it upvote because though the question says it doesnot want to use any framework, but seems to be its not possible and we need to go with any framework.

Comment: @ismailbaig: Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't. But you can use this pattern to achieve that:

```
.background-tower{
    background-image:url('tower.jpg');
}

.background-sky{
    background-image:url('sky.jpg');
}

.background-tower, .background-tower a /* <--a tags inside tower */{
    color:#fff;
}

.background-sky {
    color:#000;
}
```

And almost your html should be like:

```
<div class='background-tower'>
    <a href="#">some text</a>
    some other text,...
</div>
```

Comment: where is isBackImgTower variable used in your answer.

Comment: @ismailbaig, I tried to show a pattern instead of correcting the question itself. Like teach fishing. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looking first css medai query. If you cant find your wants, you use jquery or alternative. For example

```
if ($("#samplediv").attr("data-state") == "a value") {
$("#samplediv").addClass("class-for-a-value");
} else {
$("#samplediv").addClass("class-for-not-a-value");
}
```

that is a logical change css class. You cannot do it use only css

Comment: And how do you imagine checking background image using media queries?