# shorter way to make a div responsive

Tags: html, css

`.ains` is my central story div and need to have flexible width
is there a shorter way - some formula or anything - to say this (without javascript)

```
.ains{width:50%;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1366px){.ains{width:60%;}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px){.ains{width:70%;}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1080px){.ains{width:80%;}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 999px){.ains{width:90%;}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px){.ains{width:100%;}}
```

Comment: By doing the maths I saw you're going to have the div at ~800px at any given breakpoint. Have you considered to just specify the width of the element? `width: 800px;`

Comment: @Adriano - and what if screen is `640px` - or `1400px` - for example

Comment: You can use `width: 800px; max-width: 100%;` in this way it will be a div of 800px, unless its parent is smaller, in that case it will be 100% of its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approximation is to use `width:max(800px,50%);max-width:100%;`

```css
.ains{width:50%;height:50px;background:red;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1366px){.ains{width:60%;}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px){.ains{width:70%;}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1080px){.ains{width:80%;}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 999px){.ains{width:90%;}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px){.ains{width:100%;}}
```

```html
<div class="ains"></div>

<div style="width:max(800px,50%);max-width:100%;
background:blue;height:50px;"></div>
```

Or `clamp(50%, 800px, 100%);`

```css
.ains{width:50%;height:50px;background:red;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1366px){.ains{width:60%;}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px){.ains{width:70%;}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1080px){.ains{width:80%;}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 999px){.ains{width:90%;}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px){.ains{width:100%;}}
```

```html
<div class="ains"></div>

<div style="width:clamp(50%, 800px, 100%);
background:blue;height:50px;"></div>
```

Comment: I found this - `width:clamp(50%, 800px, 100%);` - what do you think?

Comment: @qadenza yes it should do the same ;) Don't know why I didn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

**Caution:** *It's not gonna solve the issue but it might help.*

As long as you mentioned a *Formula*, the answer is yes there is one. you can have a mathematical approach to your issue as well. Considering the slope of `-15.730` and the offset of `2347.400` in `y = slope*x + offset` formula, you can get to the ains' width accordingly.

[image]

Say we want to find out the width when on a `1080` screen. so we have `1080=-15.730*x+2347.400`:
[image]

which very closely gets us to the width point of ~`80`.([this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20for%20x&assumption=%7B%22MC%22%2C%20%22%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveEquation%22%2C%20%22solveequation%22%7D%20-%3E%221080%3D-15.730*x%2B2347.400%22))

so the `.ains` width will always be `calc((2347.400 - vw-in-px)/1573)`. but it seems like there's no way to convert vw to px in css without using js.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking for is conditionals in CSS. The way to do conditionals in CSS is exactly as you've written above unless you want to use multiple classes or use something like SASS

Here is a really good response to someone asking a similar question.

[CSS Conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129699/can-you-use-if-else-conditions-in-css)

Comment: can't find solution on your link