# How to check a CSS variable value equals another value

Tags: html, css, sass, scss-mixins

How can you check if a CSS variable is equal to a value.

*default.scss*

```
:root {
    --default-direction: ltr; 
}
```

*right.scss*

```
:root {
   --default-direction: rtl; 
}
```

I wanted to add some cases in *main.scss* based on this CSS variable value. I want something like the below code snippet. Is it possible to check variable value and how to do so?

*main.scss*

```
@if(var(--default-direction) == rtl) {
   $flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129699/can-you-use-if-else-conditions-in-css

Comment: No help as I need this check only scss without any server side support.

Comment: Selectors are themselves condition in a way, if it matches-> rules are applied. But what you try to do seems much more simple, You want to reverse the flow if direction is rtl ? in that case, set a static direction right to your flex box. so it remains always in the same direction whatever the var() value is.

Comment: I wanted to define some scss variables based on direction. Since the direction changes dynamically based on country selection, I want to change the scss variable values and use it in all scoped styles of different components. Thats why needed a condition check in this case.

Comment: I guess you need to make it first a var for scss $direction for example so you can test before compilation and  then update your css var().

Comment: Tried that as well, but it doesn't help as I'm unable to check the updated value. What I need is, for example if the direction is rtl then I have a variable $paddingStart: right; and for ltr direction $paddingStart: left;. I'm want to use this variable in my child components like padding-#{$paddingStart}: 10px;

Answer (score 0):

How I do it is creating a mixing rule for rtl:

```
@mixin rtl {
    body:lang(ar) &{
      @content;
    }
  }
```

With that mixin you can start creating your rules:

```
.flexbox {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
    @include rtl {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
}
```