# Identify user machine with PHP or other language

Tags: php, hardware, user-agent

Does PHP provide a way to identify whether a user machine is a PC with a mouse and keyboard, or a touchscreen laptop?

Comment: what language? lol nobody can read minds here

Comment: "with PHP or other language"

:)

Let's go with PHP first given it's been tagged as such.

Comment: this isn't too broad as he is only asking for a PHP method to detect either a mouse or touchscreen

Answer (score 3):

+1, Good question. Yes, identifying the user is important for better user experience.

Look into user agent detection. This might help you get started. They analyze the [**user agent (UA) string**](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/p/http_user_agent.htm) the browser sends when making requests. However, detection with PHP is probably limited, and Javascript will have to get involved to fullfill what you want.

- [`get_browser()` in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)
- [Detector](http://detector.dmolsen.com/)

There are **various ways** to detect whether a browser has a feature

- [Detecting that the browser has no mouse and is touch-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838680/detecting-that-the-browser-has-no-mouse-and-is-touch-only)
- [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) (used by Detector) this common Javascript library simplifies the task.

Look into conditional html/css/javascript:

- [Conditional Formatting in HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502431/conditional-formatting-in-html-tags)
- Also, there are css vendor prefixes/extensions for [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Mozilla_Extensions), [Webkit, used by Chrome and Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Webkit_Extensions) that only apply to a specific browser

Hope this helps you!