# Conditional coloring of text in HTML

Tags: php, html

I want to change the color of some text on my website depending on whether input from a php script is X or Y, is this possible without doing Javascript, which I would like to avoid.

I have read: [Conditional Formatting in HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502431/conditional-formatting-in-html-tags) but I am wondering if there has been any changes/updates that makes this possible now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are outputting html on the same page you can try something like this:

```
<?php
$colour = 'green';

if(rand(0, 99) >= 50) {
    $colour = 'red';
}
?>
<div style="color:<?=$colour?>;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

The rand is just to mimic the different values in a test scenario.

Comment: Apologies for a more general answer - Saberi gave a response closer to what you asked. I had an answer in my head and didn't look back at the question.

Comment: This is perfect! I used yours and output is <p>Signature verified: </p> <div style="color:<?=$sig_colour?>;"> <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['verified'];?></strong> </div>. I have one short follow up question, with the above code the green text is on a new line, is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: Everything in the div will be that colour. If you do a view source; paste the output of the section you are talking about and I'll take a look - it might be that you have the style on the wrong part of your html.

Comment: yeah exactly, but the div will also put the text on the next line, is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Ah ok. You can try adding display:inline-block to the style tag but without seeing a fuller example; it's difficult to answer for sure.

Comment: Or you can change your <p> and my <div> to both being <span> - then they should be inline.

Comment: Got it! Used span instead of Div and moved the </p> to the end. I fiddled around with the display but to no avail. The other solution worked though, thanks a whole bunch!

Answer (score 2):

**No JS:**

I think the following would work:

```
/* Define different colors to the input class */
.X{
  color: red;
}
.Y{
  color: blue;
}

/* set the input class as the input value */   
<label class="<?=value?>" name="<?=value?>"> Some Text </label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just set inject the right tags from PHP. You can do this by generating the CSS from PHP, but since its more common to write dynamic HTML with PHP and use static CSS, an inline style is probably the most appropriate approach:

```
$your_colour=($your_condition) ? "green" : "red";
print "<span style='color:$your_colour'>"; 
...
print "</span>"
```

If you are applying this in several places, then you might consider using a inline css class.

```
<style>
 .false_condition {COLOR:red}
 .true_condition{COLOR:green}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is exactly what I wanted to achieve,background colour reflecting the seriousness of blood pressure numbers, in an app I'm creating for viewing blood pressure measurements.
This is the solution i arrived at

```
<?php 
  function colorWarning($sys, $dia) {
    echo "bg-redted";
  }
?>
<span class=" <?php colorWarning($first[2], $first[3]) ?> py-1 px-4 text-white text-secondary text-center rounded"> High Normal</span>
```

That's it! Works perfectly. The CSS itself, has no variables or PHP whatsoever. The only variables or PHP I'm using, is contained in the HTML code in index.php.

The HTML with hardcoded classnames, and what I wanted the PHP code to produce, actually only the variable bg-redted.

```
<span class="bg-redted py-1 px-4 text-white text-secondary text-center rounded"> High Normal</span>
```

Later, I will improve the function to print out different classnames, green colours for lower blood pressure, and red or darkred for high blood pressure.