# How to use if/else condition in html table td

Tags: html, css

I want to ask how can I doing if/else condition in this  tag?

```
 <td data-label="Status">{{$t('Status'+item.cStatus)}}</td>
```

What I want is

```
if(item.cStatus == NW){
color:red
}
else{
color:blue
}
```

Comment: Specify the language please

Comment: And also tell, what exactly you want to do

Comment: I have reference for you, may it helps :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502431/conditional-formatting-in-html-tags

Comment: I am using vue typescript, I want to show if the data is 'NW' then the <td> will become color red. else the <td> will become blue. @AsaduzzamanAtik thanks

Comment: Tryout my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an object to `:class` (short for `v-bind:class`) to dynamically toggle classes:

```js
<td :class="[item.cStatus == NW ? 'red' : 'blue']" data-label="Status">{{$t('Status'+item.cStatus)}}</td>
```

The above syntax means the presence of the `red` class will be determined by the **truthiness** of the data property `item.cStatus == NW`.

Then you can add your desired style to `red` or `blue` class

---

You can also do it by `:style` object

---

You can find more details [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html)

Comment: Cool, it's worked well. the text color changed, can the class also changed the background-color also?

Comment: Yes, you can!...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the alternative method below:

```html
<td data-label="Status">
  {{$t('Status'+item.cStatus == NW ? 'red' : 'blue')}}
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
<th:block th:if="${item.cStatus == 'NW'}">
<td data-label="Status" style="color:red;">{{$t('Status'+item.cStatus)}}</td>
</th:block>
<th:block th:unless="${item.cStatus == 'NW'}">
<td data-label="Status" style="color:blue;">{{$t('Status'+item.cStatus)}}</td>
</th:block>
```